# Why do hot tubs dehydrate you?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, water

I was just sitting in a hot tub for a few hours with friends, and we all noticed we really wanted to drink some water. We felt dehydrated. I tried looking up why hot tubs dehydrate you and all I got were links warning that they could indeed lead to dehydration, but not why. Do hot tubs cause dehydration, and if so, why? Does it have something to do with osmosis?

Comment: I apologize if this is off topic - it seems to fall under "Explanations of observed physical or astronomical phenomena
Example: Why does one experience a short pull in the wrong direction when a vehicle stops?
" but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is a question about human physiology, not physics. It might belong at [biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ah yes I figured. Thanks, I voted to close it as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is surely off topic and will be closed. But as it happens I recently took part in an experiment that as a side effect (it wasn't the aim of the expt) measured the weight change after a 30 minute immersion in hot water (basically a hot bath).

I expected I would soak up water and get heavier, but in fact I was around 100 to 200g lighter after the bath. I would guess this is simply due to me sweating while in the bath and losing water that way. I certainly noticed a lot of sweating during the few minutes while I was cooling down after the bath. Presumably since human beings evolved in the absence of jacuzzis our physiology isn't well adapted to keeping us cool efficiently when we're immersed in hot water, and we still sweat even though it obviously doesn't cool us.

If I'm correct then the dehydration is due to sweating just as it would be if you spent the same time in a sauna or a desert at the same temperature.

Comment: You gave me an idea of an experiment. As I usually swim in the sea for 40 minutes or even an hour, I have the impression that my body imbibes water through osmosis 1) I am not thirsty, though exerting myself, 2) after about 20 minutes the need for water elimination appears. I should get an accurate scale and weigh my self before and after. This is for next year, since the meteorological prognosis is for cold weather starting next weekend.